# Force Hibernate to use my custom list implementation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a business object that exposes a list of elements for which want to **have control** on.

For that, I have created a custom List implementation (*CustomList*) with a **listener** to be notified whenever an an element added / removed.

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<ItemClass> list;

    public MyClass() {
        this.list = new CustomList<ItemClass>();
    }

    public List<ItemClass> getList() {...}
    public setList(List<ItemClass>) {...}
}
```

The problem is that, if I want to persist this object, Hibernate uses the setter to set the list with its own List implementation, thus short-circuiting my nice CostumList bahavior.

I have tried to cheat with the setter, this way :

```
public setList(List<ItemClass> newList) {
    this.list.clean():
    this.list.addAll(newList);
}
```

But this does not work either : 
**Hibernate** calls the setter first, and then add some elements to its own list. Therefore, I end up with an empty list on my side.

Is there a way I can ask hibernate to use my custom list implementation ? Or to fill it after has loaded the contents ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to do something like this:

> You could always use the setter to change the list implementation
>   (similar to what you have done). For instance:
>
> ```
> public setList(List<ItemClass> newList) {
>     // Sets the list as a custom list.
>     list = new CustomList<>(newList);
> }
> ```
>
> Yet, for that to work, you need to change the implementation of your
>   **CustomList to work as a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)**, so it will work independently of the wrapped list type.

As @millimoose has noticed, it still does not solve your problem.

A working solution could be found by using the Hibernate (or JPA) [lifecycle annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) (such as @PostPersist, @PostUpdate or @PostLoad...). So, you could use that customList.addAll() solution (after the entity has been updated, persisted or loaded).

Comment: A decorator can't track updates to the underlying list, which the OP mentioned they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: But still, hibernate will continue to add elements to its own list (newList) without notifying me. 
Can I be notified when he is done populating stuff so I can init those first elements myself by hand ?

Comment: @millimoose Sounds like you are right. I'll edit it with another suggestion. Nevertheless, I would still suggest it to work as a decorator.

Comment: @RaphaelJolivet Hibernate **should** at some point during loading the entity finish adding to the list, and only keep track of changes to that list for updating the entity. The idea of this answer is to find a lifecycle event that gets called *after* this happens, and only then wrapping the list in a decorator. As you wrap the list, handle the elements that are already there, and keep the actual state in the decorated list that Hibernate is tracking.

Comment: It worked fine with a decorator and a bit of @PostLoad.
Thanks